# Highlighting buttons for "pushed" and "disabled" status

Tags: css, forms, button

In my code I have three push buttons (`input` `type="button"`) I am using to select different divs. They are acting like toggle buttons (on/off).

In the old days I used images to display when a button was pushed or reset, but I want to do it with css now. I just am not sure how to achieve the effect.

It will also require disabling the border highlight when the button is selected.

I have looked for examples of this, but have found nothing.

Edit:

OK. I have something I can show now. The code is working to a degree. It shows the depressed look when I hold the mouse button down, but as soon as I release it goes back to normal instead of remaining depressed.

I have removed extraneous code that is not part of this issue to avoid confusion.

Edit 2:

I have noticed that (in FireFox, not sure about other browsers) the default look of the buttons shows a depressed look when the button is clicked, but it returns to normal when the mouse button is released. I would like to retain the depressed look after releasing the mouse button, and until the button is clicked a second time, or until a different button is clicked.

```css
      input:hover { color: teal; }
      .push:active { background: gray; color: aquamarine; }
      .push:inactive { background: white; color: teal; }
```

```html
      <INPUT type="button" class="push" style="font-weight: bold;">
      <INPUT type="button" class="push" style="font-weight: bold;">
      <INPUT type="button" class="push" style="font-weight: bold;">
```

Edit final:

Thanks to everyone who helped me with this issue. I have found a better solution for my purposes. Below is the final version of the code. In this version, I am merely changing the font color when the button is clicked, teal when you click it once, black if you click a different button or click the same button a second time. I am doing it all from within the javascript. In the fix, my rollover highlite broke, and the fix was to use onMouseOver and onMouseOut instead of using :hover in style tags in the head. Interestingly, it doesn't seem to want to work when I paste it into the snippet runner and separate the javascript from the html.

The rollover works, but the selected button does not show teal letters when I move the mouse away. Anyway, the code is here for those who want to play with it.`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Sample Solution Page</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    <!--
      function visInvis(id,id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6) {

        var a = document.getElementById('mySol');
        var a1 = document.getElementById('MM');
        var a2 = document.getElementById('MP');
        var a3 = document.getElementById('MBL');
        var a4 = document.getElementById('MBC');
        var a5 = document.getElementById('MPS');
        var a6 = document.getElementById('MPL');

        var b = document.getElementById('YASS');
        var b1 = document.getElementById('YM');
        var b2 = document.getElementById('YP');
        var b3 = document.getElementById('YBL');
        var b4 = document.getElementById('YBC');
        var b5 = document.getElementById('YPS');
        var b6 = document.getElementById('YPL');

        var c = document.getElementById('Tak');
        var c1 = document.getElementById('TM');
        var c2 = document.getElementById('TP');
        var c3 = document.getElementById('TBL');
        var c4 = document.getElementById('TBC');
        var c5 = document.getElementById('TPS');
        var c6 = document.getElementById('TPL');

        var d;
        var d1 = document.getElementById('MS');
        var d2 = document.getElementById('YS');
        var d3 = document.getElementById('TS');

        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        var e1 = document.getElementById(id1);
        var e2 = document.getElementById(id2);
        var e3 = document.getElementById(id3);
        var e4 = document.getElementById(id4);
        var e5 = document.getElementById(id5);
        var e6 = document.getElementById(id6);

        if(e == a && e.style.display == 'none') {
          d = d1;
          b.style.display = 'none';
          b1.style.display = 'none';
          b2.style.display = 'none';
          b3.style.display = 'none';
          b4.style.display = 'none';
          b5.style.display = 'none';
          b6.style.display = 'none';
          d2.style.color = 'black';

          c.style.display = 'none';
          c1.style.display = 'none';
          c2.style.display = 'none';
          c3.style.display = 'none';
          c4.style.display = 'none';
          c5.style.display = 'none';
          c6.style.display = 'none';
          d3.style.color = 'black';
        }

        if(e == b && e.style.display == 'none') {
          d = d2;
          a.style.display = 'none';
          a1.style.display = 'none';
          a2.style.display = 'none';
          a3.style.display = 'none';
          a4.style.display = 'none';
          a5.style.display = 'none';
          a6.style.display = 'none';
          d1.style.color = 'black';

          c.style.display = 'none';
          c1.style.display = 'none';
          c2.style.display = 'none';
          c3.style.display = 'none';
          c4.style.display = 'none';
          c5.style.display = 'none';
          c6.style.display = 'none';
          d3.style.color = 'black';
        }

        if(e == c && e.style.display == 'none') {
          d = d3;
          a.style.display = 'none';
          a1.style.display = 'none';
          a2.style.display = 'none';
          a3.style.display = 'none';
          a4.style.display = 'none';
          a5.style.display = 'none';
          a6.style.display = 'none';
          d1.style.color = 'black';

          b.style.display = 'none';
          b1.style.display = 'none';
          b2.style.display = 'none';
          b3.style.display = 'none';
          b4.style.display = 'none';
          b5.style.display = 'none';
          b6.style.display = 'none';
          d2.style.color = 'black';
        }

        if(e == a && e.style.display == 'block')
          d = d1;
        if(e == b && e.style.display == 'block')
          d = d2;
        if(e == c && e.style.display == 'block')
          d = d3;

        if(e.style.display == 'block') {
          e.style.display = 'none';
          e1.style.display = 'none';
          e2.style.display = 'none';
          e3.style.display = 'none';
          e4.style.display = 'none';
          e5.style.display = 'none';
          e6.style.display = 'none';
          d.style.color = 'black';
        }
        else {
          e.style.display = 'block';
          e1.style.display = 'block';
          e2.style.display = 'block';
          e3.style.display = 'block';
          e4.style.display = 'block';
          e5.style.display = 'block';
          e6.style.display = 'block';
          d.style.color = 'teal';
        }
      }

      function selectText(divID) //divID contains actual id of ‘div’ element
      {
        var textC=document.getElementById(divID);
        if (document.selection)
        {
          //Portion for IE
          var div = document.body.createTextRange();
          div.moveToElementText(textC);
          div.select();
        }
        else
        {
          //Portion for FF
          var div = document.createRange();
          div.setStartBefore(textC);
          div.setEndAfter(textC);
          window.getSelection().addRange(div);
        }
      }
    -->
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <TABLE style="float: left; vertical-align: top; width: 17%;">
      <TR><TH style="text-align: left; width: 65%;">Collection:</TH><TH style="width: 35%;">Revenge</TH></TR>
      <TR><TH style="text-align: left;">Level #:</TH><TH style="width: 30%;">1</TH></TR>
      <TR><TH style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; height: 49.5pt;" colspan="2">Puzzle Name</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2"><HR></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD>Width:</TD><TH style="width: 30%;">0</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>Height:</TD><TH style="width: 30%;">0</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>Boxes/Goals:</TD><TH style="width: 30%;">0</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2"><HR></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><INPUT type="button" id=MS
        style="font-weight: bold;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='teal'"
        onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'"
        onClick="visInvis('mySol','MM','MP','MBL','MBC','MPS','MPL');
        selectText('mySol');" value="My Solution"></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><INPUT type="button" id=YS
        style="font-weight: bold;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='teal'"
        onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'"
        onClick="visInvis('YASS','YM','YP','YBL','YBC','YPS','YPL');
        selectText('YASS');" value="YASS Solution"></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><INPUT type="button" id=TS
        style="font-weight: bold;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='teal'"
        onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'"
        onClick="visInvis('Tak','TM','TP','TBL','TBC','TPS','TPL');
        selectText('Tak');" value="Takaken Solution"></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2"><HR></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD>Moves:</TD><TH style="width: 30%;">
        <DIV id=MM style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=YM style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=TM style="display: none;">0</DIV></TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>Pushes:</TD><TH style="width: 30%;">
        <DIV id=MP style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=YP style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=TP style="display: none;">0</DIV></TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>Box lines:</TD><TH style="width: 30%;">
        <DIV id=MBL style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=YBL style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=TBL style="display: none;">0</DIV></TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>Box changes:</TD><TH style="width: 30%;">
        <DIV id=MBC style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=YBC style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=TBC style="display: none;">0</DIV></TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>Pushing sessions:</TD><TH style="width: 30%;">
        <DIV id=MPS style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=YPS style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=TPS style="display: none;">0</DIV></TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>Pusher lines:</TD><TH style="width: 30%;">
        <DIV id=MPL style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=YPL style="display: none;">0</DIV>
        <DIV id=TPL style="display: none;">0</DIV></TH></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2"><HR></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2">Inactive button means no solution available. Some puzzles YASS cannot solve,
        some Takaken cannot solve, and some I have not solved.</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE style="float: right; border: 1px solid; border-spacing: 0px; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top;
      width: 42%; height: 650px;">
      <CAPTION style="align: top; text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">Solution</CAPTION>
      <TR><TD style="vertical-align: top;">
        <DIV id=mySol style="display: none; width: 520px; height: 640px; word-wrap: break-word;
          overflow: auto;">My Solution</DIV>
        <DIV id=YASS style="display: none; width: 520px; height: 640px; word-wrap: break-word;
          overflow: auto;">YASS Solution</DIV>
        <DIV id=Tak style="display: none; width: 520px; height: 640px; word-wrap: break-word;
          overflow: auto;">Takaken Solution</DIV>
      </TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE style="float: center; border: 1px solid; border-spacing: 0px; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top;
      width: 40.3%; height: 650px;">
      <CAPTION style="align: top; text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">Puzzle</CAPTION>
      <TR><TD>
        <PRE style="text-align: center;"></PRE>
      </TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

`

Comment: Please add code you have tried. If possible add a fiddle too.

Comment: Be more explicit. Show us some examples on what you're trying to achieve please. I don't know what you did in the "old days".

Comment: The code I used back then has been out of my possession for a long time. I'm going back to the original geocities days and html 2.0/3.2. I don't have any examples to show you. As to what I have tried, the only thing I have tried (and it works) is to change the text color when the mouse pointer hovers over the button: input:hover { color: teal; } in style tags in the head. I do not know enough css to know what else to try. I want the button to look depressed when it is clicked once, and reset to normal when it is clicked again.

Comment: You're trying to do something like this http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSSClickEvents/index.html ??

Comment: almost, but the button needs to be changing, not a target text.

Answer (score 0):

I supose that what you are looking for is a way to change the appareance of your buttons when they are clicked.

What you can do is to create two css classes on your css stylesheet, one for active buttons and another one for inactive buttons.

Your page starts with your buttons in a determinate state, so you create them with the correspondent class

On your client code, when a button is clicked, you just change the class name it has, from active to inactive and vice versa.

*Et voilá* your styles will apply when the buttons are clicked

Comment: I think I understand this, so I will give it a try and see what I get. If it doesn't work, at least I'll have an example to show.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a purely HTML and CSS solution, you could actually use a checkbox styled to look like a button.  Something like this:

### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="input"/>
<label for="input" id="button">Push me</label>
```

### CSS

```
input { 
    display: none;
}

#button {
    border: 3px solid #52A7D3;
    background-color: #52A7D3;
    color: #000000;
}


#input ~ #button:active, #input:checked ~ #button{
    background-color: grey;
}

#button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

I have made a jsFiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/p0z88ysu/

Comment: This is surely a contender, but it is difficult for me to wrap my head around. So much css for such a small task. I hope there is a more simple way to do it. Optimally, i would like to make use of the effect that holding down the mouse button currently has. If that would remain in effect until either that button is clicked a second time, or until a different button is clicked, it would be perfect. Also, i don't mind using some javascript if it is required to achieve the effect.